# How can I make a CoreData fetch to get the most recent date associated through several relations to a subject entity?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

Say I have an entityA which has a one-to-many relation to entityB, which has a one-to-many relation to entityC which stores a date.

Since each relation is one-to-many, each date is associated to one entityA. I need to access the most recent date attached to the given objectA. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks, and sorry if this is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it.You can try both of them and decide which one is faster.

**1)** `NSExpressionDescription`

You can use this to set the propertiy you want to cath and using the min: function.More about this **Fetching Specific Values** of Core Data Progremming Guide

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html

**2)** Use Inverse Relationship

Just Fetch C-type enteties by a simple NSFetchRequest,ascending by a date attribute with fetchLimit set to one and witch `BtypeEntety.ATypeEntety` is equal to the `A` you are interested in.That's your minimum date.